# FTP to SFTP/SCP proxy?

Tags: proxy, ftp, sftp

I use quite a few web-related pieces of software such as Drupal and Xenu with features that require FTP access to the filesystem. I do have SSH access (so I can use SFTP or scp), but not FTP access (there is no FTP server).

So what I'm hoping to find is an FTP to SFTP proxy: a piece of software I can install locally that I can use as an FTP server but that actually performs SFTP to my server of choice. On Linux or Windows.

If you have used any software that does this (I can't find any with Google) what did you use, and did you run into any limitations?

Comment: Why exactly do you need plain un-ecrypted FTP when you have the secure version already working?  You should **always** use SFTP over FTP (I usually disable the latter).

Comment: @Breakthrough: It is explained in the question. Please read again and tell me what isn't clear.

Comment: A workaround that may suffice when local filesystem access is supported:  pretend that the remote filesystem is local (e.g. using SFTP as a Windows drive, see http://superuser.com/q/66470/11317).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitvise has a FTP to SFTP bridge:
https://www.bitvise.com/ftp-bridge

Supposedly MindTerm supports this:
http://helpdesk.oneonta.edu/xoops/modules/smartsection/item.php?itemid=81
http://computing.camden.rutgers.edu/unix/mindterm.php
http://people.emich.edu/tips.d/ftpbridge.php

Supposedly IBM WebSphere® MQ File Transfer Edition has http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wmqfte.doc%2Fprotocol_bridge.htm

An other idea:
I think if your FTP client supports SOCKS and your server has an FTP-server on 127.0.0.1 you can forward all the connections to the server ?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe an easier solution to your problem would be to use an SCP/SFTP over SSH. I recommend you give [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/introduction) a try. Besides, it's free.

Comment: I use it a lot, but it's not an answer to the question.